# A browser that supports css3 3d transforms?

Tags: browser, 3d, websites, css

I am doing web development on a Ubuntu machine (Lubuntu 10.10 more specifically), and wondered if there is a browser that I can install (in the repositories or otherwise) that has decent support for CSS3 3d transforms (by using the word 'decent' here, I exclude Chromium which is incredibly glitchy).

Thing is, I hate switching to a different machine that runs Windows, just to test my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if Opera supports that feature, but if it does you can install opera from their website.

Comment: It does not, unfortunately - downloaded 11.01 a few minutes ago. I do think that this property is only supported in webkit based browsers, and besides Chromium and Konqueror I haven't heard of any other webkit based browsers that run on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far, [only Webkit browsers support CSS3 3D Transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29#cite_ref-75).  Chrome/ium is probably the most popular option, so if the version you tried wasn't working, you may want to update to the very latest -- something like the [Chromium Daily Builds](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa).  If even that is too buggy to work with, you might want to try a different Webkit browser for Linux.

Midori and Epiphany are two decent options.  As an added bonus, I think both of these browsers will use the version of Webkit that you have installed on your system (unlike Chrome, which comes with its own version of Webkit).  That means that you should be able to build Webkit from the [latest nightly source release](http://nightly.webkit.org/), and Midori or Epiphany will automatically use that version.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [CSS3 Presentation and Styling](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#css3-title)

The start of the document is [here](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#landing-slide).

Everything that is explained there works perfectly under Google-Chrome, Chromium-Browser and Mozilla Firefox, tested by me.

*(Move left-right using the arrow keys)*

May be you wish to say what exactly you wish to test, and if possible, provide a sample.

Good luck.

Comment: As a reference: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com

Comment: Thank you for your observation. I didn't notice before about 3D transformations. I really appreciate a lot your feedback. I now have a question: What exactly means: "3D transforms only work in Safari and Chrome." and this seems not to be working, even when I am using Chrome to view it.

Comment: Exactly that - it is possible to make it work in Chromium/Chrome by turning on GPU Acceleration in about:flags. Only Safari supports it natively however, without further tweaking to the browser. Unfortunately, there is no version of Safari for Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 0):

New Opera 11.10 supports CSS3. [Download](http://opera.com/download) it.